# Problems with Routes (Symfony 5.0.11)

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm a beginner in Symfony and am using v5.0.11 as part of a work project (inb4: as its a work for the company I'm employed by, I have little control over updating the version).

My issue is the following: I have a controller (that extends the "CommonController") file that contains different routes leading to different URLs, supposed to be triggered by a multi-field form's button. The first route in this controller (except for the one leading to the main page) is "@Route: /global/search/" related to a "globalSearch funtion". The following routes (eg @Route: /global/product_code/{product_code}) are defined further down the document, indented at the same level and are located outside of that first "globalSearch" function.

Depending on the form's fields fill beforehand; it should send the user to a specific URL related to said field (eg: if I fill the "product code" category, it should send me to an address like "/global/product_code/{product_code}".

However, when I fill any field and press the button, it still sends me to the general search URL ("global/search") instead of the one I routed above '"global/product_code" for example.

Do you have any idea why that is ? I've gone down Symfony & Doctrine docs but couldn't find any answer for it; and from what I read I can't prioritize routes as I'm in 5.0.11.

Thanks in advance for any help.

NB: as my work concerns a sector and company bound by secret to my country's governement & multiple firms; I can't share the code online to 3rd parties; tho I will try to bring as many infos about the code as needed.

Comment: You can use bin/console debug:container debug:router to verify if it is indeed a question of route priority.  If so then one workaround is to use a routes.yaml file to generate routes instead of annotations.  Or if you don't want to completely give up annotations, you can add just the routes that you want to bump up in priority to the routing file.  But I am pretty sure the issue has nothing to do with priority.  I'd suggest other possibilities but those are top secret.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, be warned that Symfony 5.0.11 is pretty outdated, as all kinds of support for this version ended in July 2020

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without some code samples it would be hard to identify the problem and whether it's a problem at all.

But here are some ideas, how to narrow the problem down.

First:

> However, when I fill any field and press the button, it still sends me to the general search URL ("global/search") instead of the one I routed above '"global/product_code" for example.

If you're using symfony forms to create and/or render forms, it's probably `<form action="">` attribute. I assume it either blank (which will submit it to the same URL. In your case it's `/global/search`) or it is set to a specific route. (e.g `/global/search` )
In any case, you should consider @Cerads suggestion to check all available routes to find out more and find out which controller action is responsible for  `/global/product_code/{product_code}`. If there are some routes matching this pattern, they have to have a "route name" so you could search in the whole project for that route name.

`bin/console debug:router` or `bin/console debug:router | grep global`

Second:

> Depending on the form's fields fill beforehand; it should send the user to a specific URL related to

To somehow change submit-url by users-input requires JavaScript. Whether you send a single field value via AJAX or just "replace" form's `action` attribute, you have to check related JavaScript code.